# When Queue.qsize() is not 0, but why is Queue.empty() True in python multiprocessing?

Tags: python, multithreading, queue, multiprocessing

everyone,
I have a question about Queue in multiprocessing:

I use Queue to exchange data with multi processes, two processes put and one process gets. But I find that:

1. When queue.qsize() is not 0, but queue.empty() is True. And queue.get() is waiting too.
2. If queue.get() is waiting, when queue.put() is used in other process.

Code:

```
from multiprocessing import Queue

train_queue = Queue(maxsize = 50000)
****
**** Other Module
****
if train_queue.empty() == True:
        print "***** ", i, " **** queue is empty"
        print "***** queue.get, train_queue.qsize: ", train_queue.qsize()
        ti = time.time()
```

LOG:

```
***** 10 **** queue is empty
***** queue.get, train_queue.qsize: 512
***** 102 **** queue is empty
***** queue.get, train_queue.qsize: 1233
***** 189 **** queue is empty
***** queue.get, train_queue.qsize: 1865
```

Comment: Probably not the issue, but *don't use `== True`*. Leave truth testing to the `if` statement, `if train_queue.empty():` is enough.

Comment: Also, you have a *race condition*. Between the `empty()` call and the `qsize()` call, something could have been added to the queue.

Comment: Docs clearly states that qsize "Return the approximate size of the queue. Because of multithreading/multiprocessing semantics, this number is not reliable.". Note "Approximate". Don't trust qsize.

Comment: If you ever have to use qsize/empty in your concurrent program you have almost certainly a bug (the one exception being progress logging in the case of qsize) and a problem with your overall design. Ask a new question about your actual problem.

Comment: Hi, did you solve your problem?

Comment: Multiprocessing.Queue is just super bad. Also havnig empty() True when queue is NOT empty and qsize() > 0 although I'm testing empty() / qsize() in the ONLY process that PUT anything on the queue. And the queue is indeed NOT empty because other processes are still consuming from it. This means adding a sentinel at the end of the queue doesn't help. Very bad implementation.

Comment: See https://bugs.python.org/issue17985 to understand how bad the state is, the devs are ok to have basic semantics completely broken. And as for the why, they are using a thread to feed the queue. Morale: you cannot use empty()/qsize() to check that your sentinel was consumed, you have to rely on something else (eg. a sentinel on the output queue).